# NSArray? doesn't have member named "Generator"

Tags: ios, swift, nsarray

I am getting a weird error from this segment of the code:

```js
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SampleData", ofType: "plist")

let dataArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path!)

for dict: AnyObject in dataArray{ ...}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSArray? is not an NSArray. It's an optional NSArray, in other words either an NSArray or nothing at all.

Either write

```
for dict: AnyObject in dataArray!
```

which will work or crash if dataArray is nil, or write

```
if let dataArray = NSArray (contentsOfFile: path!)
{
    ...
}
```